# Is there a way to draw trees/graphs with MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax, latex

I know you can do some basic LaTeX on SE sites using MathJax. Is it possible to draw graphs (as in nodes & edges) or trees through tikz or something similar? Most of the examples I've seen are images.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tikz is a LaTeX package; there is no similar plugin for MathJax. Embedding an  image is the best available solution, see [Is there a way to draw a graph (vertices & edges) in LaTeX on this website?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11049).

That said, it's possible to [draw some trees](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/23066) with painstaking effort, but  few users are willing and able to do this.

And simple [commutative diagrams](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2324) are supported.

Answer (score 2):

You can make boxes and arrows, so it is possible to draw [box-and-pointer diagrams](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1829/9357).

The key elements are:

- To create a box: `\fbox{box}`
- To draw an arrow: `\longrightarrow`
- To label the arrow: `\overset{\mathtt{label}}{\longrightarrow}`
- To reduce code repetition, define a `\ptr{label}` command:

  ```
  \newcommand{ptr}[1]{\overset{\mathtt{#1}}{\longrightarrow}}
  ```
- To make it span multiple lines:

  ```
  \begin{align*}
      first line &alignmentpoint something something \\
      next line &alignmentpoint stuff \\
      third line &alignmentpoint stuff
  \end{align*}
  ```

Obviously, it's a hack, and it would take effort to make it look right.